# Preserving the input control structure in MLIR's TF dialect

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to generate MLIR using Tensorflow (2.2.0) as a front-end and I would like to clarify the following. 
Let's consider the example below that implements direct matrix multiplication of two 2x2 matrices.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.mlir as mlir

with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):

        @tf.function
        def mymatmul(A, B, C):
            for i in range(2):
                for j in range(2):
                    cij = 0.0
                    for k in range(2):
                        cij += A[i, k]*B[i, j]
                    C[i, j].assign(cij)


        A = tf.constant([[1., 2.], [3., 4.]])
        B = tf.constant([[2., 1.], [4., 3.]])
        C = tf.Variable([[0., 0.], [0., 0.]])
        mymatmul(A, B, C)

tf_mlir_graph = mlir.experimental.convert_graph_def(g.as_graph_def())
print(tf_mlir_graph)
```

This code emits the following MLIR.

```
module attributes {tf.versions = {bad_consumers = [], min_consumer = 12 : i32, producer = 175 : i32}} {
  func @main() {
    %0 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<0.000000e+00> : tensor<2x2xf32>} : () -> tensor<2x2xf32>
    %1 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<[[2.000000e+00, 1.000000e+00], [4.000000e+00, 3.000000e+00]]> : tensor<2x2xf32>} : () -> tensor<2x2xf32>
    %2 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<[[1.000000e+00, 2.000000e+00], [3.000000e+00, 4.000000e+00]]> : tensor<2x2xf32>} : () -> tensor<2x2xf32>
    %3 = "tf.VarHandleOp"() {_class = ["loc:@Variable"], container = "", device = "/device:CPU:0", dtype = f32, shape = "tfshape$dim { size: 2 } dim { size: 2 }", shared_name = "Variable"} : () -> tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>
    "tf.StatefulPartitionedCall"(%2, %1, %3) {Tin = ["tfdtype$DT_FLOAT", "tfdtype$DT_FLOAT", "tfdtype$DT_RESOURCE"], Tout = [], _read_only_resource_inputs = [], config = "", config_proto = "\0A\07\0A\03CPU\10\01\0A\07\0A\03GPU\10\002\02J\008\01", device = "/device:CPU:0", executor_type = "", f = @__inference_mymatmul_1160} : (tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>) -> ()
    %4 = "tf.VarIsInitializedOp"(%3) {device = "/device:CPU:0"} : (tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>) -> tensor<i1>
    %5 = "tf.ReadVariableOp"(%3) {device = "/device:CPU:0", dtype = f32} : (tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>) -> tensor<2x2xf32>
    "tf.AssignVariableOp"(%3, %0) {device = "/device:CPU:0", dtype = f32} : (tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>, tensor<2x2xf32>) -> ()
    return
  }
  func @__inference_mymatmul_1160(%arg0: tensor<2x2xf32>, %arg1: tensor<2x2xf32>, %arg2: tensor<!tf.resource>) attributes {tf.signature.is_stateful} {
    %0 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<1> : tensor<2xi32>} : () -> tensor<2xi32>
    %1 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<[1, 2]> : tensor<2xi32>} : () -> tensor<2xi32>
    %2 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<[0, 1]> : tensor<2xi32>} : () -> tensor<2xi32>
    %3 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<0> : tensor<2xi32>} : () -> tensor<2xi32>
    %4 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<2> : tensor<2xi32>} : () -> tensor<2xi32>
    %5 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<[2, 1]> : tensor<2xi32>} : () -> tensor<2xi32>
    %6 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<[1, 0]> : tensor<2xi32>} : () -> tensor<2xi32>
    %7 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<0.000000e+00> : tensor<f32>} : () -> tensor<f32>
    %8 = "tf.ReadVariableOp"(%arg2) {device = "", dtype = f32} : (tensor<!tf.resource>) -> tensor<*xf32>
    %9 = "tf.StridedSlice"(%arg0, %3, %0, %0) {Index = i32, T = f32, begin_mask = 0 : i64, device = "", ellipsis_mask = 0 : i64, end_mask = 0 : i64, new_axis_mask = 0 : i64, shrink_axis_mask = 3 : i64} : (tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %10 = "tf.StridedSlice"(%arg1, %3, %0, %0) {Index = i32, T = f32, begin_mask = 0 : i64, device = "", ellipsis_mask = 0 : i64, end_mask = 0 : i64, new_axis_mask = 0 : i64, shrink_axis_mask = 3 : i64} : (tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %11 = "tf.Mul"(%9, %10) {T = f32, device = ""} : (tensor<f32>, tensor<f32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %12 = "tf.AddV2"(%11, %7) {T = f32, device = ""} : (tensor<f32>, tensor<f32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %13 = "tf.StridedSlice"(%arg0, %6, %5, %0) {Index = i32, T = f32, begin_mask = 0 : i64, device = "", ellipsis_mask = 0 : i64, end_mask = 0 : i64, new_axis_mask = 0 : i64, shrink_axis_mask = 3 : i64} : (tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %14 = "tf.StridedSlice"(%arg1, %6, %5, %0) {Index = i32, T = f32, begin_mask = 0 : i64, device = "", ellipsis_mask = 0 : i64, end_mask = 0 : i64, new_axis_mask = 0 : i64, shrink_axis_mask = 3 : i64} : (tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %15 = "tf.Mul"(%13, %14) {T = f32, device = ""} : (tensor<f32>, tensor<f32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %16 = "tf.AddV2"(%15, %7) {T = f32, device = ""} : (tensor<f32>, tensor<f32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %17 = "tf.StridedSlice"(%arg0, %0, %4, %0) {Index = i32, T = f32, begin_mask = 0 : i64, device = "", ellipsis_mask = 0 : i64, end_mask = 0 : i64, new_axis_mask = 0 : i64, shrink_axis_mask = 3 : i64} : (tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %18 = "tf.Mul"(%17, %14) {T = f32, device = ""} : (tensor<f32>, tensor<f32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %19 = "tf.AddV2"(%16, %18) {T = f32, device = ""} : (tensor<f32>, tensor<f32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %20 = "tf.StridedSlice"(%arg1, %0, %4, %0) {Index = i32, T = f32, begin_mask = 0 : i64, device = "", ellipsis_mask = 0 : i64, end_mask = 0 : i64, new_axis_mask = 0 : i64, shrink_axis_mask = 3 : i64} : (tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %21 = "tf.Mul"(%13, %20) {T = f32, device = ""} : (tensor<f32>, tensor<f32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %22 = "tf.AddV2"(%21, %7) {T = f32, device = ""} : (tensor<f32>, tensor<f32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %23 = "tf.Mul"(%17, %20) {T = f32, device = ""} : (tensor<f32>, tensor<f32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %24 = "tf.AddV2"(%22, %23) {T = f32, device = ""} : (tensor<f32>, tensor<f32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %25 = "tf.StridedSlice"(%arg0, %2, %1, %0) {Index = i32, T = f32, begin_mask = 0 : i64, device = "", ellipsis_mask = 0 : i64, end_mask = 0 : i64, new_axis_mask = 0 : i64, shrink_axis_mask = 3 : i64} : (tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %26 = "tf.Mul"(%25, %10) {T = f32, device = ""} : (tensor<f32>, tensor<f32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %27 = "tf.AddV2"(%12, %26) {T = f32, device = ""} : (tensor<f32>, tensor<f32>) -> tensor<f32>
    "tf.ResourceStridedSliceAssign"(%arg2, %3, %0, %0, %27) {Index = i32, T = f32, begin_mask = 0 : i64, device = "", ellipsis_mask = 0 : i64, end_mask = 0 : i64, new_axis_mask = 0 : i64, shrink_axis_mask = 3 : i64} : (tensor<!tf.resource>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<f32>) -> ()
    %28 = "tf.ReadVariableOp"(%arg2) {device = "", dtype = f32} : (tensor<!tf.resource>) -> tensor<*xf32>
    %29 = "tf.StridedSlice"(%arg1, %2, %1, %0) {Index = i32, T = f32, begin_mask = 0 : i64, device = "", ellipsis_mask = 0 : i64, end_mask = 0 : i64, new_axis_mask = 0 : i64, shrink_axis_mask = 3 : i64} : (tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %30 = "tf.Mul"(%9, %29) {T = f32, device = ""} : (tensor<f32>, tensor<f32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %31 = "tf.AddV2"(%30, %7) {T = f32, device = ""} : (tensor<f32>, tensor<f32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %32 = "tf.Mul"(%25, %29) {T = f32, device = ""} : (tensor<f32>, tensor<f32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %33 = "tf.AddV2"(%31, %32) {T = f32, device = ""} : (tensor<f32>, tensor<f32>) -> tensor<f32>
    "tf.ResourceStridedSliceAssign"(%arg2, %2, %1, %0, %33) {Index = i32, T = f32, begin_mask = 0 : i64, device = "", ellipsis_mask = 0 : i64, end_mask = 0 : i64, new_axis_mask = 0 : i64, shrink_axis_mask = 3 : i64} : (tensor<!tf.resource>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<f32>) -> ()
    %34 = "tf.ReadVariableOp"(%arg2) {device = "", dtype = f32} : (tensor<!tf.resource>) -> tensor<*xf32>
    "tf.ResourceStridedSliceAssign"(%arg2, %6, %5, %0, %19) {Index = i32, T = f32, begin_mask = 0 : i64, device = "", ellipsis_mask = 0 : i64, end_mask = 0 : i64, new_axis_mask = 0 : i64, shrink_axis_mask = 3 : i64} : (tensor<!tf.resource>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<f32>) -> ()
    %35 = "tf.ReadVariableOp"(%arg2) {device = "", dtype = f32} : (tensor<!tf.resource>) -> tensor<*xf32>
    "tf.ResourceStridedSliceAssign"(%arg2, %0, %4, %0, %24) {Index = i32, T = f32, begin_mask = 0 : i64, device = "", ellipsis_mask = 0 : i64, end_mask = 0 : i64, new_axis_mask = 0 : i64, shrink_axis_mask = 3 : i64} : (tensor<!tf.resource>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<f32>) -> ()
    return
  }
}
```

What is interesting, at least for my purposes, is the loss of the loop structure of the computation.  In the `tf` dialect, the loop structure is flattened but I would like the output MLIR to reflect/preserve the original loop structure expressed in the TF operator graph. 
I suppose, another way of phrasing this question is to ask whether TensorFlow dialect supports control constructs (in my belief it does via [tf.IfOp](https://www.tensorflow.org/mlir/tf_ops#tfif_tfifop) and [tf.WhileOp](https://www.tensorflow.org/mlir/tf_ops#tfwhile_tfwhileop)) and if there are any particular syntax restrictions the input should adhere to in order to retain the loop structure.
What would be the best way to go about this?

P.S. I suspect this might have something to do with *eager execution* which is the default behavior in tf =>2.0. Maybe someone can verify this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the input computation to the following did the trick. I believe the problem was with (at least partly) the use of python variables along with `tf` variables. The following effectively preserves the symbolic structure of the computation.

```
with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        @tf.function
        def mymatmul(A, B, C, m, n):
            for i in range(m):
                for j in range(m):
                    for k in range(n):
                        C[i,j].assign(tf.math.add(C[i, j], tf.math.multiply(A[i, k], B[k, j])))

            return C

        A = tf.constant([[1., 2.], [3., 4.]])
        B = tf.constant([[2., 1.], [4., 3.]])
        C = tf.Variable((tf.zeros((2, 2), dtype=tf.float32)))
        m = tf.constant(2)
        n = tf.constant(2)
        mymatmul(A, B, C, m, n)
```

This generates the following MLIR with `tf.While`.

```
module attributes {tf.versions = {bad_consumers = [], min_consumer = 12 : i32, producer = 412 : i32}} {
  func @main() {
    %0 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<[[1.000000e+00, 2.000000e+00], [3.000000e+00, 4.000000e+00]]> : tensor<2x2xf32>} : () -> tensor<2x2xf32>
    %1 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<[[2.000000e+00, 1.000000e+00], [4.000000e+00, 3.000000e+00]]> : tensor<2x2xf32>} : () -> tensor<2x2xf32>
    %2 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<2> : tensor<i32>} : () -> tensor<i32>
    %3 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<0.000000e+00> : tensor<2x2xf32>} : () -> tensor<2x2xf32>
    %4 = "tf.VarHandleOp"() {_class = ["loc:@Variable"], allowed_devices = [], container = "", device = "/device:CPU:0", shared_name = "Variable"} : () -> tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>
    %5 = "tf.StatefulPartitionedCall"(%0, %1, %4, %2, %2) {_collective_manager_ids = [], _read_only_resource_inputs = [], config = "", config_proto = "\0A\07\0A\03CPU\10\01\0A\07\0A\03GPU\10\002\02J\008\01", device = "/device:CPU:0", executor_type = "", f = @__inference_mymatmul_3650} : (tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<2x2xf32>
    %6 = "tf.VarIsInitializedOp"(%4) {device = "/device:CPU:0"} : (tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>) -> tensor<i1>
    %7 = "tf.ReadVariableOp"(%4) {device = "/device:CPU:0"} : (tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>) -> tensor<2x2xf32>
    "tf.AssignVariableOp"(%4, %3) {device = "/device:CPU:0"} : (tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>, tensor<2x2xf32>) -> ()
    return
  }
  func @__inference_mymatmul_3650(%arg0: tensor<2x2xf32>, %arg1: tensor<2x2xf32>, %arg2: tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>, %arg3: tensor<i32>, %arg4: tensor<i32>) -> tensor<2x2xf32> attributes {tf.signature.is_stateful} {
    %0 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<[[1.000000e+00, 2.000000e+00], [3.000000e+00, 4.000000e+00]]> : tensor<2x2xf32>} : () -> tensor<2x2xf32>
    %1 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<[[2.000000e+00, 1.000000e+00], [4.000000e+00, 3.000000e+00]]> : tensor<2x2xf32>} : () -> tensor<2x2xf32>
    %2 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<1> : tensor<i32>} : () -> tensor<i32>
    %3 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<0> : tensor<i32>} : () -> tensor<i32>
    %4 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<2> : tensor<i32>} : () -> tensor<i32>
    %5:10 = "tf.While"(%3, %4, %3, %2, %4, %4, %4, %arg2, %0, %1) {_lower_using_switch_merge = true, _num_original_outputs = 10 : i64, _read_only_resource_inputs = [], body = @while_body_1410, cond = @while_cond_1400, device = "", is_stateless = false, output_shapes = [#tf.shape<>, #tf.shape<>, #tf.shape<>, #tf.shape<>, #tf.shape<>, #tf.shape<>, #tf.shape<>, #tf.shape<>, #tf.shape<2x2>, #tf.shape<2x2>], parallel_iterations = 10 : i64} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>, tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<2x2xf32>) -> (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>, tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<2x2xf32>)
    %6 = "tf.ReadVariableOp"(%arg2) {device = ""} : (tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>) -> tensor<2x2xf32>
    %7 = "tf.Identity"(%6) {device = ""} : (tensor<2x2xf32>) -> tensor<2x2xf32>
    return %7 : tensor<2x2xf32>
  }
  func @while_body_1410(%arg0: tensor<i32>, %arg1: tensor<i32>, %arg2: tensor<i32>, %arg3: tensor<i32>, %arg4: tensor<i32>, %arg5: tensor<i32>, %arg6: tensor<i32>, %arg7: tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>, %arg8: tensor<2x2xf32>, %arg9: tensor<2x2xf32>) -> (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>, tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<2x2xf32>) attributes {tf.signature.is_stateful} {
    %0 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<1> : tensor<i32>} : () -> tensor<i32>
    %1 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<0> : tensor<i32>} : () -> tensor<i32>
    %2 = "tf.Maximum"(%arg5, %1) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    %3 = "tf.FloorDiv"(%2, %0) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    %4 = "tf.FloorMod"(%2, %0) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    %5 = "tf.AddV2"(%arg2, %arg3) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    %6 = "tf.AddV2"(%arg0, %0) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    %7 = "tf.NotEqual"(%4, %1) {device = "", incompatible_shape_error = true} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i1>
    %8 = "tf.Cast"(%7) {Truncate = false, device = ""} : (tensor<i1>) -> tensor<i32>
    %9 = "tf.AddV2"(%3, %8) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    %10 = "tf.Maximum"(%9, %1) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    %11:10 = "tf.While"(%1, %10, %1, %0, %2, %arg6, %arg7, %arg2, %arg8, %arg9) {_lower_using_switch_merge = true, _num_original_outputs = 10 : i64, _read_only_resource_inputs = [], body = @while_body_1830, cond = @while_cond_1820, device = "", is_stateless = false, output_shapes = [#tf.shape<>, #tf.shape<>, #tf.shape<>, #tf.shape<>, #tf.shape<>, #tf.shape<>, #tf.shape<>, #tf.shape<>, #tf.shape<2x2>, #tf.shape<2x2>], parallel_iterations = 10 : i64} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>, tensor<i32>, tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<2x2xf32>) -> (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>, tensor<i32>, tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<2x2xf32>)
    %12 = "tf.Identity"(%6) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    %13 = "tf.Identity"(%arg1) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    %14 = "tf.Identity"(%5) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    return %12, %13, %14, %arg3, %arg4, %arg5, %arg6, %arg7, %arg8, %arg9 : tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>, tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<2x2xf32>
  }
  func @while_body_1830(%arg0: tensor<i32>, %arg1: tensor<i32>, %arg2: tensor<i32>, %arg3: tensor<i32>, %arg4: tensor<i32>, %arg5: tensor<i32>, %arg6: tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>, %arg7: tensor<i32>, %arg8: tensor<2x2xf32>, %arg9: tensor<2x2xf32>) -> (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>, tensor<i32>, tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<2x2xf32>) attributes {tf.signature.is_stateful} {
    %0 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<1> : tensor<i32>} : () -> tensor<i32>
    %1 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<0> : tensor<i32>} : () -> tensor<i32>
    %2 = "tf.Maximum"(%arg5, %1) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    %3 = "tf.FloorDiv"(%2, %0) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    %4 = "tf.FloorMod"(%2, %0) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    %5 = "tf.AddV2"(%arg2, %arg3) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    %6 = "tf.AddV2"(%arg0, %0) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    %7 = "tf.NotEqual"(%4, %1) {device = "", incompatible_shape_error = true} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i1>
    %8 = "tf.Cast"(%7) {Truncate = false, device = ""} : (tensor<i1>) -> tensor<i32>
    %9 = "tf.AddV2"(%3, %8) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    %10 = "tf.Maximum"(%9, %1) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    %11:10 = "tf.While"(%1, %10, %1, %0, %2, %arg6, %arg7, %arg2, %arg8, %arg9) {_lower_using_switch_merge = true, _num_original_outputs = 10 : i64, _read_only_resource_inputs = [], body = @while_body_2250, cond = @while_cond_2240, device = "", is_stateless = false, output_shapes = [#tf.shape<>, #tf.shape<>, #tf.shape<>, #tf.shape<>, #tf.shape<>, #tf.shape<>, #tf.shape<>, #tf.shape<>, #tf.shape<2x2>, #tf.shape<2x2>], parallel_iterations = 10 : i64} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<2x2xf32>) -> (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<2x2xf32>)
    %12 = "tf.Identity"(%6) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    %13 = "tf.Identity"(%arg1) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    %14 = "tf.Identity"(%5) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    return %12, %13, %14, %arg3, %arg4, %arg5, %arg6, %arg7, %arg8, %arg9 : tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>, tensor<i32>, tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<2x2xf32>
  }
  func @while_body_2250(%arg0: tensor<i32>, %arg1: tensor<i32>, %arg2: tensor<i32>, %arg3: tensor<i32>, %arg4: tensor<i32>, %arg5: tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>, %arg6: tensor<i32>, %arg7: tensor<i32>, %arg8: tensor<2x2xf32>, %arg9: tensor<2x2xf32>) -> (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<2x2xf32>) attributes {tf.signature.is_stateful} {
    %0 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<1> : tensor<i32>} : () -> tensor<i32>
    %1 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<1> : tensor<2xi32>} : () -> tensor<2xi32>
    %2 = "tf.AddV2"(%arg7, %0) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    %3 = "tf.AddV2"(%arg6, %0) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    %4 = "tf.Pack"(%3, %2) {axis = 0 : i64, device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<2xi32>
    %5 = "tf.Pack"(%arg6, %arg7) {axis = 0 : i64, device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<2xi32>
    %6 = "tf.AddV2"(%arg2, %0) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    %7 = "tf.Pack"(%3, %6) {axis = 0 : i64, device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<2xi32>
    %8 = "tf.Pack"(%6, %2) {axis = 0 : i64, device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<2xi32>
    %9 = "tf.Pack"(%arg6, %arg2) {axis = 0 : i64, device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<2xi32>
    %10 = "tf.Pack"(%arg2, %arg7) {axis = 0 : i64, device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<2xi32>
    %11 = "tf.AddV2"(%arg2, %arg3) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    %12 = "tf.ReadVariableOp"(%arg5) {device = ""} : (tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>) -> tensor<2x2xf32>
    %13 = "tf.ReadVariableOp"(%arg5) {device = ""} : (tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>) -> tensor<2x2xf32>
    %14 = "tf.StridedSlice"(%13, %5, %4, %1) {begin_mask = 0 : i64, device = "", ellipsis_mask = 0 : i64, end_mask = 0 : i64, new_axis_mask = 0 : i64, shrink_axis_mask = 3 : i64} : (tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %15 = "tf.StridedSlice"(%arg8, %9, %7, %1) {begin_mask = 0 : i64, device = "", ellipsis_mask = 0 : i64, end_mask = 0 : i64, new_axis_mask = 0 : i64, shrink_axis_mask = 3 : i64} : (tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %16 = "tf.StridedSlice"(%arg9, %10, %8, %1) {begin_mask = 0 : i64, device = "", ellipsis_mask = 0 : i64, end_mask = 0 : i64, new_axis_mask = 0 : i64, shrink_axis_mask = 3 : i64} : (tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %17 = "tf.Mul"(%15, %16) {device = ""} : (tensor<f32>, tensor<f32>) -> tensor<f32>
    %18 = "tf.AddV2"(%14, %17) : (tensor<f32>, tensor<f32>) -> tensor<f32>
    "tf.ResourceStridedSliceAssign"(%arg5, %5, %4, %1, %18) {Index = i32, T = f32, begin_mask = 0 : i64, device = "", ellipsis_mask = 0 : i64, end_mask = 0 : i64, new_axis_mask = 0 : i64, shrink_axis_mask = 3 : i64} : (tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<2xi32>, tensor<f32>) -> ()
    %19 = "tf.Identity"(%arg1) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    %20 = "tf.Identity"(%11) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    %21 = "tf.AddV2"(%arg0, %0) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    %22 = "tf.Identity"(%21) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i32>
    return %22, %19, %20, %arg3, %arg4, %arg5, %arg6, %arg7, %arg8, %arg9 : tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>, tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>, tensor<2x2xf32>, tensor<2x2xf32>
  }
  func @while_cond_2240(%arg0: tensor<i32>, %arg1: tensor<i32>, %arg2: tensor<i32>, %arg3: tensor<i32>, %arg4: tensor<i32>, %arg5: tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>, %arg6: tensor<i32>, %arg7: tensor<i32>, %arg8: tensor<2x2xf32>, %arg9: tensor<2x2xf32>) -> tensor<i1> {
    %0 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<0> : tensor<i32>} : () -> tensor<i32>
    %1 = "tf.GreaterEqual"(%arg3, %0) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i1>
    %2 = "tf.Less"(%arg3, %0) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i1>
    %3 = "tf.Greater"(%arg2, %arg4) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i1>
    %4 = "tf.LogicalAnd"(%2, %3) {device = ""} : (tensor<i1>, tensor<i1>) -> tensor<i1>
    %5 = "tf.Less"(%arg2, %arg4) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i1>
    %6 = "tf.LogicalAnd"(%1, %5) {device = ""} : (tensor<i1>, tensor<i1>) -> tensor<i1>
    %7 = "tf.LogicalOr"(%6, %4) {device = ""} : (tensor<i1>, tensor<i1>) -> tensor<i1>
    %8 = "tf.Less"(%arg0, %arg1) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i1>
    %9 = "tf.LogicalAnd"(%8, %7) {device = ""} : (tensor<i1>, tensor<i1>) -> tensor<i1>
    %10 = "tf.Identity"(%9) {device = ""} : (tensor<i1>) -> tensor<i1>
    return %10 : tensor<i1>
  }
  func @while_cond_1820(%arg0: tensor<i32>, %arg1: tensor<i32>, %arg2: tensor<i32>, %arg3: tensor<i32>, %arg4: tensor<i32>, %arg5: tensor<i32>, %arg6: tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>, %arg7: tensor<i32>, %arg8: tensor<2x2xf32>, %arg9: tensor<2x2xf32>) -> tensor<i1> {
    %0 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<0> : tensor<i32>} : () -> tensor<i32>
    %1 = "tf.GreaterEqual"(%arg3, %0) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i1>
    %2 = "tf.Less"(%arg3, %0) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i1>
    %3 = "tf.Greater"(%arg2, %arg4) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i1>
    %4 = "tf.LogicalAnd"(%2, %3) {device = ""} : (tensor<i1>, tensor<i1>) -> tensor<i1>
    %5 = "tf.Less"(%arg2, %arg4) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i1>
    %6 = "tf.LogicalAnd"(%1, %5) {device = ""} : (tensor<i1>, tensor<i1>) -> tensor<i1>
    %7 = "tf.LogicalOr"(%6, %4) {device = ""} : (tensor<i1>, tensor<i1>) -> tensor<i1>
    %8 = "tf.Less"(%arg0, %arg1) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i1>
    %9 = "tf.LogicalAnd"(%8, %7) {device = ""} : (tensor<i1>, tensor<i1>) -> tensor<i1>
    %10 = "tf.Identity"(%9) {device = ""} : (tensor<i1>) -> tensor<i1>
    return %10 : tensor<i1>
  }
  func @while_cond_1400(%arg0: tensor<i32>, %arg1: tensor<i32>, %arg2: tensor<i32>, %arg3: tensor<i32>, %arg4: tensor<i32>, %arg5: tensor<i32>, %arg6: tensor<i32>, %arg7: tensor<!tf.resource<tensor<2x2xf32>>>, %arg8: tensor<2x2xf32>, %arg9: tensor<2x2xf32>) -> tensor<i1> {
    %0 = "tf.Const"() {value = dense<0> : tensor<i32>} : () -> tensor<i32>
    %1 = "tf.GreaterEqual"(%arg3, %0) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i1>
    %2 = "tf.Less"(%arg3, %0) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i1>
    %3 = "tf.Greater"(%arg2, %arg4) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i1>
    %4 = "tf.LogicalAnd"(%2, %3) {device = ""} : (tensor<i1>, tensor<i1>) -> tensor<i1>
    %5 = "tf.Less"(%arg2, %arg4) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i1>
    %6 = "tf.LogicalAnd"(%1, %5) {device = ""} : (tensor<i1>, tensor<i1>) -> tensor<i1>
    %7 = "tf.LogicalOr"(%6, %4) {device = ""} : (tensor<i1>, tensor<i1>) -> tensor<i1>
    %8 = "tf.Less"(%arg0, %arg1) {device = ""} : (tensor<i32>, tensor<i32>) -> tensor<i1>
    %9 = "tf.LogicalAnd"(%8, %7) {device = ""} : (tensor<i1>, tensor<i1>) -> tensor<i1>
    %10 = "tf.Identity"(%9) {device = ""} : (tensor<i1>) -> tensor<i1>
    return %10 : tensor<i1>
  }
}
```

This is still too verbose and dense to my liking (and `for` is my preferred loop construct whenever possible), but that will have to be addressed during dialect conversion and is a different problem altogether.